# Normalization in curve fitting

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test, fitting

I'm doing a stat course and I don't understand this at all. Would really appreciate if someone could explain under what circumstance the fitting function is supposed to be a PDF and when it should just be a function.

Let's say I have some data that looks Gaussian. I want to try and fit a Gaussian function to it. Should I fit the Gaussian PDF or just the Gaussian function? I'm really confused about this concept because the teacher switches back and forth between fitting PDF's and functions and I don't understand why. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! The "F" in "PDF" is "function". Switching between the terms is sloppy instruction for an intro class, but it has some legitimacy.

Comment: So just to be absolutely clear: in that sense you always fit a PDF when curve fitting?

Comment: It will depend on exactly what you mean, but if you have some data, plot a histogram, decide the shape looks Gaussian, and want to fit a Gaussian distribution, yes.

Comment: If the thing you're estimating is literally a distribution, then obviously it needs to be normalized (it must integrate to 1 or it's not a distribution). If it's a functional relationship, then you wouldn't -- but then why would you limit yourself to functions proportional to densities? Most relationships are not normalizable.